# Issue trying to merge data.frames after converting numeric class to data.frame

Tags: r, csv, merge

I'm having some trouble trying to merge two data.frames in R and I believe this is caused by converting class `numeric` to a `data.frame`.

Background: I want to see the proportion of protein expression for different subcellular locations compared to the total expression of all proteins in a number of cell lines. I got the following datasets by doing `colSums()` resulting in:

dput(actin_expression)

```
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 3, 24.00000001, 27.00000001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), .Names = c("HAP1.wt_P8255.1", "HAP1.wt_P8255.2", 
"HAP1.wt_P8254.1", "HAP1.wt_P8254.2", "HAP1.kd_P8253.1", "HAP1.kd_P8253.2", 
"HAP1.kd_P8252.1", "HAP1.kd_P8252.2", "HAP1.kd_P8249.1", "HAP1.kd_P8249.2", 
"HAP1.kd_P8248.1", "HAP1.kd_P8248.2", "HAP1.wt_P8247.1", "HAP1.wt_P8247.2", 
"HAP1.wt_P8246.1", "HAP1.wt_P8246.2", "HAP1_P7964.1", "MDS_P7246.1", 
"A673_P6591.1", "K562__P5494.1", "K562_P5464.1", "K562_P5359.1", 
"K562_P5359.2", "K562_P5358.1", "K562_P5358.2", "K562_P5357.1", 
"K562_P5357.2", "K562_P5356.1", "K562_P5356.2", "K562_P5355.1", 
"K562_P5355.2", "K562_P5269.1", "K562_P5269.2", "K562_P5268.1", 
"K562_P5268.2"))
```

dput(aggresome_expression)

```
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 3, 24.00000001, 27.00000001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), .Names = c("HAP1.wt_P8255.1", "HAP1.wt_P8255.2", 
"HAP1.wt_P8254.1", "HAP1.wt_P8254.2", "HAP1.kd_P8253.1", "HAP1.kd_P8253.2", 
"HAP1.kd_P8252.1", "HAP1.kd_P8252.2", "HAP1.kd_P8249.1", "HAP1.kd_P8249.2", 
"HAP1.kd_P8248.1", "HAP1.kd_P8248.2", "HAP1.wt_P8247.1", "HAP1.wt_P8247.2", 
"HAP1.wt_P8246.1", "HAP1.wt_P8246.2", "HAP1_P7964.1", "MDS_P7246.1", 
"A673_P6591.1", "K562__P5494.1", "K562_P5464.1", "K562_P5359.1", 
"K562_P5359.2", "K562_P5358.1", "K562_P5358.2", "K562_P5357.1", 
"K562_P5357.2", "K562_P5356.1", "K562_P5356.2", "K562_P5355.1", 
"K562_P5355.2", "K562_P5269.1", "K562_P5269.2", "K562_P5268.1", 
"K562_P5268.2"))
```

dput(whole_protein_expression)

```
structure(c(5792.666666662, 5696.833333328, 5926.333333331, 5698.499999993, 
91.5, 5491.999999989, 5905.99999999, 5875.166666664, 6283.666666659, 
6221.333333328, 6461.833333324, 6551.999999995, 6162.499999993, 
6291.333333332, 6092.333333334, 5860.666666665, 66602.24999992, 
102735.516666836, 128849.166666626, 161552.66666675, 162444.416666818, 
22056.083333343, 21648.08333335, 21857.000000007, 21648.500000005, 
20084.166666684, 20250.333333338, 19233.750000023, 19152.416666677, 
18134.916666664, 18319.833333336, 21743.00000001, 21708.41666667, 
21191.500000012, 20974.833333327), .Names = c("HAP1.wt_P8255.1", 
"HAP1.wt_P8255.2", "HAP1.wt_P8254.1", "HAP1.wt_P8254.2", "HAP1.kd_P8253.1", 
"HAP1.kd_P8253.2", "HAP1.kd_P8252.1", "HAP1.kd_P8252.2", "HAP1.kd_P8249.1", 
"HAP1.kd_P8249.2", "HAP1.kd_P8248.1", "HAP1.kd_P8248.2", "HAP1.wt_P8247.1", 
"HAP1.wt_P8247.2", "HAP1.wt_P8246.1", "HAP1.wt_P8246.2", "HAP1_P7964.1", 
"MDS_P7246.1", "A673_P6591.1", "K562__P5494.1", "K562_P5464.1", 
"K562_P5359.1", "K562_P5359.2", "K562_P5358.1", "K562_P5358.2", 
"K562_P5357.1", "K562_P5357.2", "K562_P5356.1", "K562_P5356.2", 
"K562_P5355.1", "K562_P5355.2", "K562_P5269.1", "K562_P5269.2", 
"K562_P5268.1", "K562_P5268.2"))
```

Divide the colSums of `actin_expression` over the `whole_protein_expression`. Divide the colSums of `aggresome_expression` over the `whole_protein_expression`.

```
actin <- actin_expression/whole_protein_expression*100
aggresome <- aggresome_expression/whole_protein_expression*100
class(actin) # Class numeric
actin <- as.data.frame(actin) # Change to a data.frame 
aggresome <- as.data.frame(aggresome)
head(actin)
```

I would like to name the columns so I can do a `new-df <- merge(actin,aggresome=by="cell_line")`

I try to name the first column `cell_line` as follows:

```
names(actin) <- c("cell_line", "actinFilaments")
Error in names(actin) <- c("cell_line", "actinFilaments") : 
'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

Something is odd here - I believe it's telling me I only have one column?

Usually when you do `write.csv()` the first column is like an index `1:nrow` (not sure if that is the right term) but when I `write.csv(actin, "actin.csv")` this is not the case.

What's the explanation for why most times writing a csv file results in the first column being an index (and how could one prevent this)? Why are my cell lines (possibly) being considered an index (and how could I prevent this)?

Many thanks to any R-wizards who can share some knowledge on class conversions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with a lot of vectors instead of putting everything in a dataframe:

Create a df:

```
df <- data.frame(actin_expression, aggresome_expression, whole_protein_expression)
```

put the names in a column:

```
df <- data.frame(Names = rownames(df), df, row.names = NULL)
```

create new columns:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
       mutate(actin = actin_expression/whole_protein_expression*100,
              aggresome = aggresome_expression/whole_protein_expression*100)
```

Let me know if that is along what you're looking for?

also: you're using vectors still when you were trying to write.csv. If its a dataframe, it will show up as the first column, and not an index like you're referencing.

```
actin <- data.frame(df2$Names, df2$actin)
write.csv(actin, "actin.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Matt-W. this is a good way of keeping an analysis file so you can remember the intermediate values (e.g. error checking maybe) as it keeps actin_expression, aggresome_expression and whole_expression in the dataset. What I didn't mention in the question was I need to do this for 32 subcellular locations so I would end up with 65 columns with your method. Also, thank you for clearing up that my data.frame class was actually still a vector (row names for cell_line like @Mako212 said) and not an index! One minor addition, you need `library(dyplr)` for the `mutate`

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that. I usually remember that piece. `dplyr` is very handy. I'm not sure how you're reading all those 65 columns in, I'm hoping theres a way you can read it in so that it is in dataframe format instead of typing out the data.frame command to create it. 
And yes, each column is a vector, a dataframe is really just a list of vectors of the same size, and homogeneous classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is just that your `cell_line` values are stored as row names, rather than an actual column. I didn't meticulously review your analysis to make sure it didn't cause issues anywhere else, but to fix the issue with the final data frame:

```
require(tibble)

df <- rownames_to_column(actin, "cell_line")
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Mako212 this works also!